# Matplotlib save figure with url as svg results in error

Tags: python, matplotlib, url, svg

I'm trying to create a barplot where each bar also links to an url.

However, when I try to save the figure as an svg I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'` originating from matplotlib's *backends_svg.py*.

Without the *url* it works fine. With a *gid* instead of *url* the behaviour is the same

MWE:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(["A","B"], height=[10, 4], url=["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", "https://www.google.com/"])
fig.savefig(filename, format="svg")
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for `ax.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) state that `url` must be a string, but you use a list…

Why an exception is not raised when you use a list, instead of a string, when you call `ax.bar`?

```
ax.bar(["A","B"], [10, 4], url=["https://en.wikipedia.org", "https://www.google.com/"])
```

Because Matplotlib doesn't type check the expression you assign to `url`.  An exception is raised only when the SVG backend *tries to use* the value of `url`, in particular the backend assumes that it's dealing with a string and uses a string method, but your value is a list and has not the method required, hence the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

What can you do to avoid the problem arising when Matplotlib *tries to use* the value of`url`?

- If you want to associate a link to the bar-plot as a whole you must use a
  single string.
- If you want to associate a link to each of the bars in the graph you
  can do as follows

  ```
  ...
  bars = plt.bar((1, 2), (3, 4))
  for bar, url in zip(bars, ["https://en.wikipedia.org", "https://www.google.com/"]):
      bar.set_url(url)
  ...
  ```

Of course, nothing restrains you from associating a link to the bar-plot AND to each one of the bars, but

```
bars = plt.bar((1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), url='https://www.google.com/0')
for n, bar in enumerate(bars, 1): bar.set_url('https://www.google.com/%d'%n)
plt.savefig('delenda.est', format='svg')
```

as you can see, only the links pertaining to the bars are saved in the SVG file:

```
$ grep google delenda.est 
    <a xlink:href="https://www.google.com/1">
    <a xlink:href="https://www.google.com/2">
    <a xlink:href="https://www.google.com/3">
$
```

Comment: Thanks: I indeed wanted to add a link to each bar. I included the suggested method in my code, and now the plot can be saved without any issues. However, the resulting svg does not seem to contain the urls as a href

Comment: @Jonathan The links are correctly saved to the SVG output, please see my edit.  I don't know what your further problem may be and because I'm no a SVG person I couldn't even try to help — but afaict I've correctly solved the problem you reported in your question.

Comment: It seems like I made a rookie mistake by including the svg in an <img> tag instead of as a string if that makes sense. Now everything works perfectly.